# Remove array based on key value

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [abc] => value
        [def] => value
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [abc] => value 2
        [def] => value
    )
```

In this case, I want to remove `array 1` IF the values of `[def]` match. How can I remove an array if the values match?

Comment: Value of `[def]` matches with whom?

Comment: Tried `if` and `unset`? Tried anything at all?

Comment: @AhsanAli if it matches the value of `def` in any of the arrays

Comment: @phpca  Your question is unclear in the sense that you want to compare  a third value to all `['def']` and based on equality you want to delet that particualr array or you want to comare values of `[def]` with-each-other and want to remove duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array_search` for this. Something like this in your loop

```
if (($key = array_search($delete_value, $your_array)) !== false) {
unset($your_array[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go loop through your array and unset match index like this,

```
  <?php
      $arr = Array(Array(
            'abc' => "value",
            'def' => "value"
          ),Array(
            'abc' => "value 2",
            'def' => "value"
          )); 


   for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){
    if($arr[$i]['def'] == $arr[$i+1]['def']){
      unset($arr[$i+1]);
    }
   }
   print_r($arr);
   ?>
```

Check this i have created demo [link](https://eval.in/954408).
I hope it helps.